# multiple net.tcp calls to a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, net.tcp

I a have a problem, my client calls a Wcf Service via Net.Tcp.
In a Cycle after almost 200 calls, the service remains locked for approximately 10 minutes, and blocks any other client working with net.tcp protocol.

I Have other clients who call the wcf service via Https, these ones continue to work without problems.

What kind of misconfiguration can be?

Thanks!

here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AttoCreditoConnection" connectionString="MyConnectionstring" />
  </connectionStrings>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" name="AttoCredito.AttoCreditoBiz.AttoCreditoWcf">
        <endpoint address="tcp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
         name="AttoCreditoNetTcp" contract="AttoCredito.AttoCreditoBiz.IAttoCreditoWcf" />
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurityBinding"
         name="AttoCreditoWcfHttp" contract="AttoCredito.AttoCreditoBiz.IAttoCreditoWcf" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:808" />
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:443" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAttoLegacyWcf" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000"
          textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="10000000"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportNetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
          openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="50" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxBufferSize="10000000" maxConnections="50" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="10000000"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:30:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="DocumentaleNetTcp">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurityBinding" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
          openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="10000000"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:30:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
              establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="DocumentaleHttp">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/AttoLegacy/AttoLegacyWcf.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAttoLegacyWcf" contract="AttoLegacyHost.IAttoLegacyWcf"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IAttoLegacyWcf" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/AnagraficaBiz/AnagraficaSrv.svc/tcp"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
        contract="AnagraficaHost.IAnagraficaSrv" name="AnagraficaNetTcp" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/AttoBiz/AttoExtraction.svc/tcp"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
        contract="AttoHost.IAttoExtraction" name="AttoNetTcp" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/ContoCorrenteBiz/ContoCorrenteSrv.svc/tcp"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
        contract="CcHost.IContoCorrenteSrv" name="ContoCorrenteNetTcp" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/ContrattoBiz/ContrattoWcf.svc/tcp"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
        contract="ContrattoHost.IContrattoWcf" name="ContrattoNetTcp" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/MembershipBiz/Membership.svc/tcp"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
        contract="MembershipHost.IMembership" name="MembershipNetTcp" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/ToponomasticaBiz/Toponomastica.svc/tcp"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
        contract="TopoHost.IToponomastica" name="ToponomasticaNetTcp" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/CreditoBiz/CreditoWcf.svc/tcp"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
        contract="CreditoHost.ICreditoWcf" name="CreditoNetTcp" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/EnteDebitoreBiz/EnteDebitoreWcf.svc/tcp"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
        contract="EnteDebitoreHost.IEnteDebitoreWcf" name="EnteDebitoreNetTcp" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/AciBiz/AciBiz.svc/tcp"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
        contract="AciHost.IAciBiz" name="AciBizNetTcp" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/DocumentaleBiz/DocumentaleWcf.svc/tcp"
        behaviorConfiguration="LargeList" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportNetTcpBinding"
        contract="DocumentaleHost.IDocumentaleWcf" name="DocumentaleNetTcp" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LargeList">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LargeList">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post the bindings section of your web.config for the WCF service? I suspect you may be hitting a default max connection setting with the net.tcp binding.

Comment: Are you disposing of your clients after use? I have experienced a similar issue in the past because net.tcp uses a connection pool. Failing to dispose of the client does not return the connection to the pool.

Comment: Hi spodger! thanks for the reply!, i added the web.config as u asked :)

Comment: Amith.. yes i'm sure that i dispose my clients.. thanks...

Comment: @stef doesn't look like that then. Have you tried adjusting the timeouts on the net.tcp binding? Also, even though the service is locked, do the 200 calls complete successfully and how long do they take?

Comment: @spodger Yes i've tried to calibrate the timeouts.. but doens't seem the problem.

I give you an example of what is its behavior: let's suppose i have to make  300 calls. the application starts the cycle and occupies 5 seconds per call until it arrive near the 200 calls, then the wcf stops for about 10 minutes.. and then restarts .. at the end it complete the work.. is like the wcf goes in 'pause' but only for the net.tcp side, if in this time i use the https app the service answers correctly..

Comment: You might be crashing the server's TCP stack, with TCP connections being left in a wait state.  We had this happen with one of our applications that had high use with Net.Tcp connections.   We had to change some registry settings - I'll see if I can dig up the relevant information in the next day or two.